# CUDA library not found error with object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

I've been following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COlbP62-B-U to run an object detection program from jupyter notebook. When I open the object-detection tutorial, it shows me the following error: `could not find 'cudart64_90.dll'. tensorflow requires that this dll be installed in a directory that is named in your %path% environment variable.` I've already installed CUDA 9.0 developer kit, and the file `'cudart64_90.dll'` exists in my NVIDIA directory. Is the .dll file in the right place? Why am I getting this problem?

Comment: What's in your `%PATH%` environment variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved it was installing cuda with the network installer type, the local type installation didn't install the necessary dll.